# Can't install Vision Workbench

Tags: linux, boost, computer-vision, configure

I am trying to install the Vision Workbench on my computer, following the instructions from this homepage: http://lunokhod.org/?p=13. I have installed all dependencies but I have libboost1.54-all-dev instead since I am using Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.4).

After that I have created the config.options file I do `./autogen` and `./configure`.

However, I get the following in the logfile:

> configure:20861: /usr/include/boost is missing these required libraries: BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS BOOST_FILESYSTEM BOOST_THREAD
>
> Checking for a boost in /usr/include/boost-*
>
> Checking for a boost in /usr/local/cuda/include
>
> Checking for a boost in /usr/local/cuda/include/boost-*
>
> configure:20875: checking for package BOOST
>
> HAVE_PKG_BOOST=no

However, in  `/usr/include/boost/` I have booth `program_options`, `filesystem` and `thread`.

The `.so` files are under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for opencv, boost and flann, but somehow it can only find flann.

Does anyone have an idea about where the error might be?

EDIT: In the log-file I saw that the program looked for cxcore when it searched for opencv, but in the new version it is called opencv_core so I did a symbolic link from cxcore to opencv_core and then ./configure finds opencv. However, boost is still a problem and is necessary to build the program.

EDIT2:
I have now downloaded an earlier version of boost (1.42), and almost all boost programs are found except BOOST_THREAD. When I install the boost library I get the following messages:

```
error: #error "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
```

/ Erik

Comment: Make simlink with /usr/include/boost/ to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/include/boost/`

Comment: Hi, it does not help. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
./configure --with-boost="path/to/boost"
```

if you have more than one version of boost installed, you may need to also set environment variables

```
HAVE_PKG_BOOST=yes
PKG_BOOST_CPPFLAGS=/path/to/boost
PKG_BOOST_LDFLAGS=/path/to/boost
```