# Install boost 1.42 on Mint 17 Thread disabled

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

This is related to this question: [Can't install Vision Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201034/cant-install-vision-workbench).

I need to install boost1.42 in order to compile Vision workbench. I have downloaded the 1.42 package http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.42.0/ and extracted it. First I run `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/myname/` and then `./bjam install`. Everything works fine except for

```
error: #error "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
```

So the thread package is not installed correctly and that means I cannot generate a make-file for Vision Workbench.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?

/ Erik

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

```
$ cd ~/boost_1_42_0
$ bjam --build-dir=/tmp/build-boost toolset=gcc stage
```

should build static and shared non-debug multi-threaded variants of the libraries. To build all variants, pass the additional option, “--build-type=complete”.

If this doesn't work for you, then potentially your toolset is not being detected correctly (try specifying it). This is not unlikely since Boost 1.42.0 is really old, and probably could never know about the compiler version you're using.

As an aside, the BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS is known to make no difference for recent boost version.

Comment: There is nothing built under thread, and what would be the difference between this and running bootstrap and then bjam install?